# Convert Outlook.MailItem body and attachment to UTF8 or stream

Tags: outlook-addin, mailitem

I have to POST the content- mail body and attachment of mailitem in UTF-8 or streambyte format with all email body format preserved.
What can be the best possible way to proceed with this requirement.
Thanks

Comment: What are you havign problems with? Encoding UTF-16 data returned from Outlook? Converting an Outlook message to txt / html / MIME format? Or something else?

Comment: the formatting of the mail body is not preserved when using MailItem.body or MailItem.HTMLBody to any string value.  My requirement is to fetch the  mailitem body and then POST the content using REST api.

Comment: What exactly is not preserved? The formatting? Or the Unicode characters? Not preserved where? If you are sending HTML body, where exactly does it get corrupted? You need to be a lot more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property of the MailItem class which returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail()  
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties.  
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem  
 'Create email item  
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
 With objMail  
 'Set body format to HTML  
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML  
 .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"  
 .Display  
 End With  
End Sub
```

To get actual bytes you can use the `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` method.

In the case of web add-ins you can use the following code:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
  "html",
  { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
  function callback(result) {
    // Do something with the result.
  });
```